# Object Level Validation with Knockout-Validation

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a parent object with a list of children. I would like to validate that the sum of one of the properties on the children equals the value of a property on the parent.

In the fiddle below: How can I check if the sum of the "stock amounts" equals to the "portfolio total amount"

http://jsfiddle.net/casudeo/xR5st/

Comment: Would you be open to an alternate method, such as calculating the parent by summing the children to ensure it is always correct?

Comment: Yes, I would be. Can you elaborate further what you have in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading Tyrsius' comment above, I gave my question some further thought and came up with a solution. I ended up creating a custom validator to which I passed a function that iterated over the children. I would still welcome any other solutions and/or comments.

My solution: http://jsfiddle.net/casudeo/z6yEu/